# Why is spec(R) with the Zariski topology sober?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I believe I can see a way to do this if R is noetherian, using the decomposition into primary ideals. But the general case alludes me.

Comment: You mean "eludes" not "alludes".

Comment: Wikipedia cites "Hart, Klaas Pieter; Nagata, Jun-iti; Vaughan, Jerry E. (2004). Encyclopedia of general topology. Elsevier. pp. 155–156. ISBN 978-0-444-50355-8" for soberity of spectral spaces.

Comment: I think this is just saying that every irreducible closed subset has a generic point. This is a proof that can be found in say Mumford or Hartshorne. I think the rough idea is that an affine scheme is irreducible iff it has a minimal prime.